# C# send a simple SSH command

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm a young a student and received my homework for this week. It's pretty difficult for me because I have to create a program, that is able to connect to an SSH server and send the command "etc/init.d/networking restart".

I should program this application in C# and I'm pretty new to it (Just have learned from some school lessons). I also should create a GUI.

I understand the basics of C# (loop, if etc...).

I've already created GUI, menus, buttons and a log listbox.
GUI = 3 textboxes (ip, username, password) and a button to connect.

[image: screenshot of ui]

[image: screenshot of code]

I'm coding with Microsoft Vistual Studio.

My question is: How can I establish an SSH connection to my server?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.dart.com/sftp-ssh-code-examples-samples.aspx)

Comment: It would also be amazing for us if you share what you have actually tried for that....

Comment: Hi, thx for your fast answers

JacobSeleznev Thanks for this website. But I just can't afford this product.

@LolCoder For sure :D
I've created a GUI
[Click Me](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/haru-4-a87f-png-nb.html)
Here a picture of the code (well^^)
[Click Me](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/haru-5-e4da-png.html)

Comment: @justinb138 Thanks for your solution. I've downloaded the library from the download page. Now a little question: How can I implement this library in my program?

Comment: Start Here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx

Comment: @justinb138 I'm pretty sure he's not writing an ASP.NET web site based on the screenshot.

Comment: ssh.net doesn't support sha-2 and you should expect issues when connecting to new OS like Fedora 35

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I used [SSH.Net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) in a project a while ago and was very happy with it. It also comes with a good documentation with lots of samples on how to use it.

The original package website can be still found [here](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/), including the documentation (which currently isn't available on GitHub).

For your case the code would be something like this.

```
using (var client = new SshClient("hostnameOrIp", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.RunCommand("etc/init.d/networking restart");
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: where did you find SSH.NET samples?  Thanks

Comment: It's available under Downnloads on their codeplex page as "SshNet Help": http://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120565. Not the most common way to supply documentation but it's there at least.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, I have downloaded the SSH.NET and if I want to call this particular Unix file `anly_load_int.sh` from .net.. what would the RunCommand look like..?

Comment: Well depending on where on the target machine the file is located it should be something like `sh /path/to/anly_load_int.sh`.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, thanks. For others, if you don't see content when viewing the .chm file, remember to rt click on it in your file manager and in properties tick the "unblock" checkbox.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you need to explicitly disconnect if you are using your client in a `using` block?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will do a clean disconnect when disposing the client, but it doesn't hurt to disconnect yourself. I think that example was from their documentation however so maybe it was needed back then?

Comment: I think this is unsecured. How is the certification handled?

Comment: Well using username and password isn't the best way to handle SSH connections but that was what the OP asked for. If you want to use certificates to authenticate then SSH.Net supports that as well.

Comment: Sadly, CodePlex's shutdown means documentation isn't available any more.

Comment: But documentation appears to be available at [Nudoq](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/SSH.NET).

Comment: The docs at nudoc seems to be simply generated from the assembly and doesn't contain the samples that the old file had. They also seem to have a new chm file on github now but it seems to be the same as the Nudoq ones. The original one can be found at https://github.com/ch4/ch4zilla/blob/master/Renci.SshNet/Documentation/Help/SshNet.Help.chm though it might be a bit dated but it check the SshClient class documentation for a sample of how to really use it.

Comment: Disconnect() call is required? Dispose() call Disconnect()?

Comment: I haven't worked with this in quite a while but generally disposing of something should close its underlying connection. So it probably isn't required.

Answer (score 9):

```
SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("192.168.10.144", 22, "root", "pacaritambo");
cSSH.Connect();
SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("exec \"/var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf\"");
cSSH.Disconnect();
cSSH.Dispose();
```

//using SSH.Net

Comment: this worked for me as i needed to use a port that wasnt the default.

Comment: You should actually put a using at the beginning of line 1.  This keeps you from having to remember to Dispose on line 5 and will dispose even in the event of an error which prevents memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

SharpSSH should do the job. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET

Comment: Dont support multiple connections :(

Comment: Tamir SSH is deprecated. It uses old easy-hacking protocols. SSH.net is a newer and more secure solution.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but for me none of the solution worked unfortunately. Actually, If you need to execute multiple commands, and also the commands depend on each other (first command modified the environment, e.g. variables, that are used by the latter commands), you have to execute them within one channel. Use a shell syntax for that, like `&&` or `;`:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("hostnameOrIp", "username", "password"))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (var command = client.CreateCommand("command1 && command2"))
    {
        Console.Write(command.Execute()); //Don't forget to Execute the command
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For .Net core i had many problems using SSH.net and also its deprecated. I tried a few other libraries, even for other programming languages. But i found a very good alternative.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443701/8529170