# Copying or moving a remote file using SSH.NET with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I know that I can upload and download files from/to a SFTP server using `SftpClient` class of SSH.NET library but I am not sure how can this class be used for copying or moving a remote file on the SFTP server. I also did not find relevant material on internet. How can i copy or move a remote file from directory A to directory B, using SSH.NET library and C#.

**Update:**
I also tried experimenting with `SshClient` class using the below code but it does nothing, neither any error nor any exception.

```
ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo("FTPHost", 22, "FTPUser",
new AuthenticationMethod[]{

   // Pasword based Authentication
   new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("FTPUser","FTPPass")
   }                
   );

using (var ssh = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
{
    ssh.Connect();                
    if (ssh.IsConnected)
    {                    
         string comm = "pwd";
         using (var cmd = ssh.CreateCommand(comm))
         {
            var returned = cmd.Execute();
            var output = cmd.Result;
            var err = cmd.Error;
            var stat = cmd.ExitStatus;
         }
     }
   ssh.Disconnect();
}
```

On Visual Studio console, i get the below output.

> *SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : SendMessage to server 'ChannelRequestMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST : #152199'.
>
> SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : ReceiveMessage from server:
>   'ChannelFailureMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE : #0'.*

Comment: are you able to telnet the ftp server in cmd?

Comment: I can successfully connect and copy paste files using WinSCP utility. Apart from that, I can successfully connect and download files using the 'SftpClient' class of SSH.NET library.

Comment: How about if you use RunCommand instead of CreateCommand?

Comment: This link might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169396/c-sharp-send-a-simple-ssh-command

Answer (score 22):

With the NuGet package SSH.NET by Renci I use the following:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.SftpClient;    

...

        SftpClient _sftp = new SftpClient(_host, _username, _password);
```

To Move a file:

```
        var inFile = _sftp.Get(inPath);
        inFile.MoveTo(outPath);
```

To Copy a file:

```
       var fsIn = _sftp.OpenRead(inPath);
       var fsOut = _sftp.OpenWrite(outPath);

        int data;
        while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
            fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

        fsOut.Flush();
        fsIn.Close();
        fsOut.Close();
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest and best solution here, its also the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Was there a reason you didn't flush `fsIn`?

Comment: I think the fsOut.Flush() essentially forced an fsIn.Flush() but not 100% sure

Comment: note that MoveTo will move all the files to the new directory

Comment: I think it must be `Open(outPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);` instead of `OpenWrite(outPath)`. Because `OpenWrite` **not overwrite** file. https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/ab2ccc40bce835ce1d3c136aa702459bfd9948b7/src/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs#L1581

Comment: or `Create(outPath)`

Answer (score 20):

In addition to SSH.NET's `SftpClient`, there is also the simpler `ScpClient` which worked when I ran into `SftpClient` issues. `ScpClient` only has upload/download functionality, but that satisfied my use case.

Uploading:

```
using (ScpClient client = new ScpClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (Stream localFile = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
    {
         client.Upload(localFile, remoteFilePath);
    }
}
```

Downloading:

```
using (ScpClient client = new ScpClient(host, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (Stream localFile = File.Create(localFilePath))
    {
         client.Download(remoteFilePath, localFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. Make sure to include the SSH.NET in your project. I used the Nuget package manager.

Comment: Is it possible to have any info about progress of uploading?

Answer (score 16):

Moving a remote File can be done using SSH.NET library. Available here: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Here is sample code to move first file from one source folder to another. Set private variables in the class according to the FTP set up.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Sftp;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class RemoteFileOperations
{
    private string ftpPathSrcFolder = "/Path/Source/";//path should end with /
    private string ftpPathDestFolder = "/Path/Archive/";//path should end with /
    private string ftpServerIP = "Target IP";
    private int ftpPortNumber = 80;//change to appropriate port number
    private string ftpUserID = "FTP USer Name";//
    private string ftpPassword = "FTP Password";
    /// <summary>
    /// Move first file from one source folder to another. 
    /// Note: Modify code and add a for loop to move all files of the folder
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveFolderToArchive()
    {
        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(ftpServerIP, ftpPortNumber, ftpUserID, ftpPassword))
        {
            SftpFile eachRemoteFile = sftp.ListDirectory(ftpPathSrcFolder).First();//Get first file in the Directory            
            if(eachRemoteFile.IsRegularFile)//Move only file
            {
                bool eachFileExistsInArchive = CheckIfRemoteFileExists(sftp, ftpPathDestFolder, eachRemoteFile.Name);

                //MoveTo will result in error if filename alredy exists in the target folder. Prevent that error by cheking if File name exists
                string eachFileNameInArchive = eachRemoteFile.Name;

                if (eachFileExistsInArchive)
                {
                    eachFileNameInArchive = eachFileNameInArchive + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmss");//Change file name if the file already exists
                }
                eachRemoteFile.MoveTo(ftpPathDestFolder + eachFileNameInArchive);
            }           
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if Remote folder contains the given file name
    /// </summary>
    public bool CheckIfRemoteFileExists(SftpClient sftpClient, string remoteFolderName, string remotefileName)
    {
        bool isFileExists = sftpClient
                            .ListDirectory(remoteFolderName)
                            .Any(
                                    f => f.IsRegularFile &&
                                    f.Name.ToLower() == remotefileName.ToLower()
                                );
        return isFileExists;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about checking if the file already exists before moving it. I was getting a general `Failure` error, but in reality it was caused by this issue.