# How to execute a shell script on a server using windows application

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I have built a Windows application using C-Sharp which basically connects to database server hosted on a linux server. Is there a way using which I can modify the same application so that I can execute unix commands which shall be executed on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute shell commands remotely using SSH, take a look at this:
[C# send a simple SSH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169396/c-sharp-send-a-simple-ssh-command)